# Bootstrap 4: Vertical Line in mobile and full screen sizes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how it currently looks:
[image: how it currently looks]  
how it should look:
[image]

I'm trying to build a module for my website and I'm having issues with placing a vertical hr that should have kind of a fade on the top and bottom.

x = some image with title below, I = vertical hr

mobile:

| x I x | 
 | x I x | 
 |   x    |

full screen:
"| x I x I x I x I x |"

my current html file (not using any scss, css etc. at the moment). the {{ . }} parts are from the hugo framework that I'm using and represent text.
I currently deleted every try I had for placing a vertical line. hope somebody could help me with my issue.

```html
{{ $file := index $.Site.Data (.Get "folder") (.Get "file") }}
<section class="five-icon">
   <div class="container">
     <h2 class="text-center mb-3">{{ $file.title }}</h2>
     <div class="row text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
      {{ range $file.images}}
        <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ .img_path }}" alt="{{ .img_alt }}" title="{{ .img_title }}">
 <div class="mt-3">
   <b class="text-center bold c-white">{{ .title_bold }} </b>
   <p class="text-center c-white" style="hyphens: auto;">{{ .title }}</p>
 </div>
        </div>
      {{end}}
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the rendered HTML instead of the templated code?

Comment: added some screenshots

Comment: The desired screenshot doesn't show the outer vertical lines line the text diagram in your question

Comment: What do you mean with outer vertical lines?
the vertical lines should just be between the images

Comment: This `| x I x I x I x I x |` has line outside the outermost X's

Comment: I used capital "i"'s as the spacers, guess you couldn't see that. sorry my mistake!

As I said its just between the images! :)